# IIS - Detecting Brute Force Logins and Password Spraying

Tags: iis, brute-force-attacks, microsoft, intrusion-detection

#### TLDR;

What techniques are being used to detect brute force logins and/or password spraying on IIS hosted websites (including SharePoint, OWA, etc.)?

#### ModSecurity

There are many tools for other operating systems to address this with the primary being `ModSecurity`. While it has been ported to support IIS, it doesn't integrate with IIS as well as it does with other platforms. Besides, I would be surprised to hear of any SharePoint or OWA implementations using IIS ModSecurity. If you're out there, I encourage you to post your setup here.

#### Multi-factor or Captcha

Both are viable options to **prevent** these attacks but they don't necessarily **detect** and also fail in the following ways:

1. Steps are added to the login process for **all** users just to block these login abuses from a small subset of users.
2. Some implementations will only display the additional method after a successful username/password combination has been submitted.

#### Proxy

Placing a hardware device(s) or cloud service in front of an IIS pool is a viable option. However many identify a brute force login as successive `POST` requests during a short interval which can easily lead to false-positives.

#### SIEM / Splunk

Centralized logging works though it can be expensive both monetarily as well as time invested to build rules.

#### Rate Limiting

There are modules within IIS which block IP addresses based on connection rates. This is not the same thing as what I'm asking even if technically these login attempts would trigger a rate filter.

Answer (score 0):

`WebsiteFailedLogins` is a PowerShell module available on [GitHub](https://github.com/phbits/WebsiteFailedLogins) and [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WebsiteFailedLogins) which addresses these concerns.

The [README](https://github.com/phbits/WebsiteFailedLogins/blob/master/README.md) has detailed information though here's a brief overview:

- Only requires access to the IIS logs and can run from an entirely different system. No changes are needed to IIS.
- Uses `Microsoft Logparser` to parse the IIS logs (required prerequisite).
- Identifies failed logins based on the HTTP response code.
- Configured via an `.INI` file allowing different configurations for each website.
- Alerts generated via: Standard Out, Email, and/or Event Log
- Automated via Scheduled Tasks

Being available on PowerShell Gallery, the following command will install this module :

```
Install-Module -Name WebsiteFailedLogins
```